# Introduce a format in a group of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried this code:

```
Tuple = (1, 2, 3)
 
def str_sum(Tuple):
    return '{} + {} = {}'.format(*Tuple)

L1 = [1, 2, 5]
L2 = [5, 6, 8]

def Sum(L1, L2):
    return list(map(lambda x, y: x + y, L1, L2))

SUM = Sum(L1, L2)

table = zip(L1, L2, SUM)

def TABLE(table):
    return list(map(lambda triplet: str_sum(triplet), table))

TABLE(table)
```

But I get a result of `[]`, when I expected `[('1 + 5 = 6'), ('2 + 6 = 8'), ('5 + 8 = 13')]`. Why?

Comment: Your code produces exactly that, just without the strange single-item-parenthezation?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Sorry I was very unclear there.. I'm assuming they're calling `TABLE(table)` multiple times. Or printing `list(table)` somewhere. Which would work fine in Python 2.

Comment: Sorry Andrey, as you say it is not a 'table' only a list of tuples. I just called it TABLE. I have just discovered that I had to put:

Comment: table = list(zip(L1, L2, SUM)), instead only table = zip(L1, L2, SUM). Thanks